# Unix: Limiting the amount of lines of output from DIFF command

Tags: shell, unix

this is a rather low-level question but how do you limit diff's output to (for example) 5 lines.

I am running bourne shell and I know about diff -c and diff -c 5, but none of those commands are working for me. Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which diff are you using, on NetBSD, I can limit it using the following:

```
% diff ~/.zshrc* | grep '[<>]' | head -5
< setopt autocd interactivecomments
< CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
< DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"
< #plugins=(git)
> plugins=(git)
```

Hope that helps!